# npm main:index.js for browser repos

Tags: browser, npm, module, package.json

I have a couple of repos I want to publish on npm. But these are browser repos, thus pose a problem: the `main` property in package.json appears to be for specifying a node (not browser) module.

From https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#main

> **main**
>
> The main field is a module ID that is the primary entry point to your program. That is, if your package is named foo, and a user installs it, and then does require("foo"), then your main module's exports object will be returned.
>
> This should be a module ID relative to the root of your package folder.
>
> For most modules, it makes the most sense to have a main script and often not much else.

So what should I use for a npm package for browser repos? Just omit the field? Point to the repo bundle? Something else?

Comment: The Rollup repo has this discussion: https://github.com/rollup/rollup/wiki/pkg.module. Basically it seems like "main" should point to a "legacy" bundle, while "module" (or "jsnext:main") should point to a modern ES Module (I've got both in my dist/). Is this standard? It appears to be for either browser or node modules.

Answer (score 0):

I checked out several more browser repos and it appears that this is the current convention (Taken from the Three.js & Rollup github repos):

- "main": "build/three.js",
- "jsnext:main": "build/three.module.js",
- "module": "build/three.module.js"

`main` points to the `<script>` code while `jsnext:main` and `module` point to the es6 module.

There are a few naming conventions for the module bundle:

- foo.module.js
- foo.es.js
- foo.mjs

and so on.

https://github.com/rollup/rollup/wiki/pkg.module, referred above, appears to be a reasonable reference. Google this for more:

> main jsnext:main module properties package.json

Bottom line: there are conventions but no standards.